# Tracking child processes sequentially

Tags: shell-script, gnome-terminal, exit-status, processes, sshpass

I'm running few commands on a remote server, by **sshpass**.

```
  gnome-terminal --maximize 
  --tab --title='aTask' -e "sshpass -p "afsd@#$5u89f"  ssh root@192.168.0.125 'command1 && command2'" \
```

So my question is, what if my last command is `mvn clean install`, then how may I know that the build was successful?

In a way I need to track down my first child process whether it has completed all the commands successfully, so that I can start another child process sequentially.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to run sequentially then the exit code is all you need;

```
command && echo "it worked"
```

or

```
command || echo "we are having a bad day"
```

If gnome-terminal or sshpass is not returning the correct return code file a bug report and use an alternative.

If you want to run in parallel use [xargs](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xargs) -P or [parallel](https://linux.die.net/man/1/parallel) where the

> exit status is the combination of the exit statuses of each command
>   ran, ORed together. (Thus, if any one command exits nonzero, parallel
>   as a whole will exit nonzero.)

If one of your commands is returning before execution use an alternative or make your commands adopt an asynchronous design pattern (re-invent the wheel) eg by appending

```
 ; echo $(date) $? > task1.r
```

then waiting for all tasks to complete;

```
while [ $(cat task*.r 2>/dev/null | wc -l) -lt $TASK_COUNT ] ; do
    sleep 1
done
grep -P " [^0]$" task*.r && echo "we are having a bad day"
```